# How do I prevent runoff from bar soap damaging the caulk in my shower?

Tags: bathroom, shower, caulking

I recaulked part of my shower about a year ago. After a couple of months, I noticed that the caulk had worn off just below my in-wall soap dish, where the extra soap runs down the wall. I recaulked, but have once again run into the same issue. I'm using [DAP Kwik Seal Plus](http://www.dap.com/product_details.aspx?BrandID=21&SubcatID=5), which is designed for bath applications. I am making sure to thoroughly clean before recaulking, so I do not believe this has to do with a poor application job.

Has anyone ever run into an issue like this before? Is there either a different product or a better way to apply this caulk that will resolve this issue?

Comment: I have the same problem - I'd love to hear if there was a resolution?

Comment: To be honest, the issue kinda stopped. There's still a bit of a notch in the last bead line I made but it hasn't gotten any worse. Maybe different soap? Or maybe there was something else at play that resolved itself?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have cleaned off the surface thoroughly. I would probably try to sand the area where you want the caulk. I would only imagine that if there is any soap residue that the caulk would just slip away. Curious if you tried that, I'm sure you have, if not I hope this helps.

Comment: I didn't try sanding, though I did thoroughly clean the surface. My guess is that the soap is somehow getting underneath the caulk with time and causing it to lift. If I don't hear any other advice, I'll give the sanding a try. If that doesn't do it, I might just try a different product.